# How to learn Azure SQL Database with low cost?

Tags: azure

I would like to know which could be the best aproach to get learn Azure SQL Database with low cost. If i create an Account, it just works by 30 days (free account) and I need more than this.
So, basically I need an account which can allow me to use:

Azure SQL Database (can be basic tier) 
Azure Blob Storage 
Azure Data Factory 
Azure VM

With this information, have some way to get this services with low cost to learn Azure?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

One solution would be to upgrade your free account to Pay-as-you-go account. 
https://azure.microsoft.com/en-us/offers/ms-azr-0003p/
With this you can try a lot of services from azure. Many services are charged based on the usage and for your training purpose that would incur the cost of nearly nothing bease usage would be very less. You can delete the resources as soon as you finished learning in order to keep your account clean.